# Books about things that maybe don't exist

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Here as soft question to know what think people. I was thinking about odd perfect numbers, see for example some online encyclopedia about this subject, when I have thought that (at least I think so) there isn't in the literature a specific book dedicated to odd perfect numbers.

This is the situation, I know articles and even that are in the literature  thesis about odd perfect numbers, but I don't know a book published and entirely dedicated to odd perfect numbers. And there are tons of pages dedicated to odd perfect numbers but I believe that nobody wanted to publish a book about something that perhaps does not exist.

Then I thought if there are in the literature some books or monographic entirely dedicated to some mathematical object which existence is an open problem, that is an unsolved problem.

> **Question.** Just as curiosity, do you know a mathematical book dedicated entirely to a mathematical object (from a branch/field of mathematics) whose existence is an open problem currently? **Many thanks.**

Comment: [This meme page](https://www.facebook.com/WaitNoButWhat/?ref=all_category_pyml_rhc) is the closest thing I know

Comment: Many thanks for the reference @Javi

Comment: On the other hand, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element.

Comment: I don't have a specific book reference, but much of cryptography is based on the assumed existence of [one-way functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function) which is open.

Comment: More generally, most of complexity is based on the assumption of problems in NP that are not in P.

Comment: Many thanks for your reference @lhf

Comment: Many thanks @JairTaylor for your feedback

Comment: It's not a book, but it looks like there's [a chapter](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-72126-2_7) of "The Riemann Hypothesis: A Resource for the Afficionado and Virtuoso Alike" called "Assuming the Riemann Hypothesis and Its Extensions..." about several proofs you could do with the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution @MarkS.